# Devices/Printers list not loading on Windows 7 with Bluetooth enabled

Tags: windows-7, printing, bluetooth, services

I'm having a weird recurring issue on my Win7 machine. It has Bluetooth, is sometimes connected to some Bluetooth devices, and it has a printer attached and a few network printers configured.

After a fresh boot, when I go to print something, **the list of printers never loads** and the app freezes. Similarly, the "Devices and Printers" list in Control Panel does not load, either.

It has taken me a lot of experimentation but I've found a procedure that fixes this behavior:

1. Stop **`BluetoothService`**, **`BluetoothSupportService`** services
2. End `BTTray`, `BluetoothComStack` processes
3. Stop and restart print spooler service
4. Start `BluetoothService`, `BluetoothSupportService` services

It has gotten painful to execute those steps each boot and whenever else printing stops working.

Are there **any other ways** to resolve this conflict between printing and Bluetooth functionality?

Comment: Sounds like you print spooler is crashing.  Do you have a bluetooth printer?  Is there anything interesting in the Event Logs regarding printers, the spooler and/or bluetooth?

Comment: @techie007 One of the printers is connected via USB, while the other two are shared over HomeGroup. But there are some Bluetooth devices under Devices and Printers. I'll check the logs now.

Comment: @techie007: nope, nothing in the logs except the following message pretty often: `Windows cannot store Bluetooth authentication codes (link keys) on the local adapter. Bluetooth keyboards might not work in the system BIOS during startup.`